Deduce template parameters for std::variant template parameter
I have a template class that takes std::variant as a template parameter:
template<class T>
class X
{
};

X<std::variant<int, float>> x;

I want to add a constraint for T to be derived from std::variant.
Then I want to extract template parameters of this variant to use them inside the class.
Like this:
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_base_of_v<std::variant<T::_Types>, T>, // _Types = int, float
bool> = true>
class X
{
    std::tuple<T::_Types> t; // std::tuple<int, float>
};

X<std::variant<int, float>> x;

The problem is that I cannot get these int, float parameters from the variant type.
Is there a way to do this in C++17?
This variant comes from return type of a function.
Because of this I cannot change it for something like variant parameters instead (to take int, float directly).

Deriving from std::variant is not a good idea.

std::variant_alternative and std::variant_size

The types_list type traits provides a specialized tuple for the different types that constitute the specialization of the template class T, otherwise provides an empty tuple. For simplicity, it is used the standard std::tuple.
To implement the technique, it is sufficient to add a partial specialization that accepts a generic class and its list of template arguments.
Example:
template <typename>
struct types_list
{ using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <template <typename...> typename T, typename ...Args>
struct types_list<T<Args...>>
{ using type = std::tuple<Args...>; };

template <typename T>
using types_list_t = typename types_list<T>::type;

On the other hand, the is_variant type trait verifies whether the type T is a specialization of std::variant.
To implement the condition, it is sufficient to add a partial specialization that accepts a std::variant specialization.
Example:
template <typename>
struct is_variant
 : std::false_type {};

template <typename ...Args>
struct is_variant<std::variant<Args...>>
 : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_variant_v = is_variant<T>::value;

Thus, the class can be re-implemented in the following way.
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_variant_v<T>>>
class X
{
  types_list_t<T> t;
};


So how can I use this in my example? I need a template class X<T> that takes variant<int, float> as T and can access the parameter pack int, float inside. Can You provide an example?

How do you accept types derived from std::variant, and how do you extract the template arguments of std::variant.

@HolyBlackCat, in the comment, the OP asks to constraint the class in order that it take a specialization of std::variant as T. Thus, I provide a particular case of the experimental is_specialization_of type trait.

My bad, overlooked that one.

You could generalise types_list to transform to any other template: template <typename, template <typename...> typename T> struct types_list; template <template <typename...> typename In, typename ...Args, template <typename...> typename Out> struct types_list<In<Args...>, Out> { using type = Out<Args...>; };

@Caleth, you are right. I could also generalize the is_variant type trait to is_specialization_of, but I preferred to be nearer to the OP's needs.

To get a parent std::variant from a class derived from it (if I understand you correctly, you want to accept derived classes too), do this:
template <typename ...P>
std::variant<P...> &VariantIdentity(std::variant<P...> &);

template <typename T>
using ToBaseVariant = std::remove_reference_t<decltype((VariantIdentity)(std::declval<T &>()))>;

Then you can extract the arguments from the variant using partial specialization. E.g. of a base class of X, or as the other answer suggests, a completely separate class.
template <typename T>
class XBase;

template <typename ...P>
class XBase<std::variant<P...>>
{
    std::tuple<P...> t;
};

template <typename T>
class X : XBase<ToBaseVariant<T>>
{
    using XBase<ToBaseVariant<T>>::XBase;
};


How is the VariantIdentity() function implemented? Does it return the input reference unchanged?

@LoS It has no implementation. It doesn't need one because it's only called inside decltype.
